# PHP instanceof and is_a when checking error object

Tags: php

I have function for exception handling. I'm trying to check which class exception object is instance of, but couldn't figure why `instanceof` is not working and on other hand `is_a()` is working correctly.

Here is code:

```
public function throwException($exception = null)
{
    $message = ""
    if ($exception instanceof MyNameSpace\Exception\ValidationException) {
         $message .= "One";
    }

    if (is_a($exception, 'MyNameSpace\Exception\ValidationException')) {
          $message .= "Two";
    }

    return $message;
}
```

Output of this function is always "`Two`" but it should be "`One Two`".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `instanceof` needs fully qualified classname. So this should work.

```
function throwException($exception = null)
{
    $message = "";
    if ($exception instanceof \MyNameSpace\Exception\ValidationException) {
         $message .= "One";
    }
    
    if (is_a($exception, 'MyNameSpace\Exception\ValidationException')) {
          $message .= "Two";
    }

    return $message;
}
```

Or

```
use MyNameSpace\Exception\ValidationException;


function throwException($exception = null)
{
    $message = "";
    if ($exception instanceof ValidationException) {
         $message .= "One";
    }
    
    if (is_a($exception, 'MyNameSpace\Exception\ValidationException')) {
          $message .= "Two";
    }

    return $message;
}
```

Comment: It seems that `if ($exception instanceof \MyNameSpace\Exception\ValidationException)` it working fine, but `if ($exception instanceof ValidationException)` not

Comment: Are you sure that you also added `use MyNameSpace\Exception\ValidationException;` Example - https://3v4l.org/MA5nS